# Eclipse won't update after adding project to workspace folder

Tags: java, eclipse, workspace

I added a Java project (containing one default package with 2 classes) to my folder which I declare as my workspace in Eclipse. But when I launch Eclipse, it does not add this project in the package explorer. What can I do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't copy files or folders to your workspace folder, you have to [import the project](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-importproject.htm) into Eclipse:

1. From the main menu bar, select  command link `File > Import....` The Import wizard opens.
2. Select `General > Existing Project into Workspace` and click <kbd>Next</kbd>.
3. Choose either `Select root directory` or `Select archive file` and click the associated <kbd>Browse</kbd> to locate the directory or file containing the projects.
4. Under Projects select the project or projects which you would like to import.
5. Click Finish to start the import.

Comment: glad to hear @derthomas... as you are new to StackOverflow... if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. Of course **There is no obligation to do this**.

Comment: okay. since it was helpful I accepted your answer Jordi Castilla. Actually I tried to upvote it, to find out that I am not allowed to do this at the moment.

Comment: @derthomas soon you will have enough rep to vote up (and down later) if you contribute a bit inside SO....

Answer (score 0):

Click with right button on the folder containing sources and select use as source folder